# Child window events not firing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window, dom-events

I'm trying to get an access token to be authorize some api calls to GOG api.

The problem is that in the documentation, it states that I need to open a window pointing to auth.gog.com/auth with some params and after login in correctly a redirection will be done to https://embed.gog.com/on_login_success .

So when my react app fires up I open a new window and then register to the onload event (just testing) and the onload event is never called.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={_clickHandler}>CLICK HERE</button>
    </div>
  );

  function _clickHandler()
  {
    let slaveWindow:(Window  | null) = window.open("https://auth.gog.com/auth?client_id=46899977096215655&layout=client2&redirect_uri=https://embed.gog.com/on_login_success?origin=client&response_type=code");
    if(slaveWindow!=null)
    {
      /*
      console.log("--------> "+slaveWindow);
      
      slaveWindow?.addEventListener("load", (ev:Event) => {
        console.log("Loaded!");
        return null;
      });
      */
     slaveWindow.onload = ()=>{alert("Child window has been loaded!")};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your origin is the same as `https://auth.gog.com/` you will not be able to access the onload event or any window properties and methods on `slaveWindow` object.

This is because the browser enforces the Same-origin policy on windows opened with window.open.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: So, there's no way to do this process from a react app? It seems same thing happens if I try to use an iframe. I have ran out of options. I think I will add a new question anyway pointing to this specific case of gog auth. thanks!

Comment: I looked up the API documentation for gog, and it looks like you are out of luck. It says "Similar to OAuth2", but clearly it's not meant to be used this way. Sorry. Maybe try reaching out to their developers for a solution?

Comment: Yes, I will try that too. Thanks!